# not sure why this Perl regex doesnt work (character class)

Tags: regex, perl, regex-negation, character-class

I'm trying to add a char in front of another certain char unless its already preceded by the char I'm trying to inject. This works fine (insert an n before any Z unless it already has an n before it):

```
s/([^n])Z/$1nZ/g;
```

except on word boundaries preceded by nothing. So to fix that I tried:

```
s/([\b^n])Z/$1nZ/g; # does not work

s/(\b|[^n])Z/$1nZ/g; # does work
```

Why didn't #1 work? Seems legit?

Comment: If the `^` isn't at the beginning of the character class, it means the literal character `^` *not* negate this character class.

Comment: You can't have positive and negative match in the same character class, a negative class start with ^ so [\b^n] match any word boundary, ^ or n

Comment: Note that `[\b^n]` is a character class with three or four elements (`^` and `n` are easy; `\b` might be 'backspace' or backslash and `b`); it doesn't matter which since neither is what you're seeking.  Many metacharacters lose their special meaning inside a character class.

Answer (score 5):

Two problems with `[\b^n]`:

- `^` only negates the character class if it's the first character.
- `[...]` matches a character, but you're trying to match something other than a character. In there, `\b` there represents character `08` (backspace).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys- never knew that ^ was different in position 1,  in a CC.

I move it around outside of a CC (to tag a beginning) and it works as expected. I guess I see why they did it (so you can use ^ within [] to indicate caret not negation). But it seems like escaping it would have had the same effect. Sometimes I wonder what Larry was thinking but I don't see him anymore since our company cut OSCON travel...

Much appreciated...